# Expecting Items for Html DropDownFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hi When I use the following for my dropdown

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.OIC_2, new SelectList(ViewBag.StaffMembers, "Value", "Text"))
```

I am getting the following error even though there is data in the viewbag for staff members

Viewbag.StaffMembers is made up from

```
public void GetStaffMemebers() {
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var items = _context.StaffMember.Where(w=>w.isAcitve ==true && w.isDeleteted ==false).ToList();
    foreach (var item in items) {

            SelectListItem listItem = new SelectListItem();
            listItem.Text = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName ;
            listItem.Value = item.Id.ToString();
            listItems.Add(listItem);
   }
        ViewBag.StaffMembers = listItems;        
}
```

Error

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable
> items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable
> selectedValues, string dataGroupField)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items,
> string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items,
> string dataValueField, string dataTextField) CallSite.Target(Closure ,
> CallSite , Type , object , string , string )
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4<T0, T1, T2, T3,
> TRet>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
> AspNetCore.Views_MISObjects_Edit.b__27_0() in
> Edit.cshtml
> +
> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.OIC_2, new
> SelectList(ViewBag.StaffMembers, "Value", "Text"))

Comment: Where is your Action method?

Comment: are you calling `GetStaffMemebers` method from controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try as follows:

```
public void GetStaffMemebers() 
{
    var items = _context.StaffMember.Where(sm => sm.isAcitve ==true && sm.isDeleteted ==false).Select(sm => new 
    {
         Name =  sm.FirstName + " " + sm.LastName,
         Id = sm.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.StaffMembers = items;        
}
```

Now make sure that `GetStaffMemebers()` has been called in your action method.

Then in the view as folows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OIC_2, new SelectList(ViewBag.StaffMembers,"Id","Name"), "Select Member");
```

Comment: Why did they change from using SelectList been using that method for years.

Comment: @rogue39nin Look at the [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). It expects IEnumerable of item.